# What 'him' refers to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

> "You're under-age!" Mrs Weasley shouted at here daughter as Harry approached. "I won't permit it! The boys, yes, but you, you've got to go home!"
>
> "I won't!"
>
> Ginny's hair flew as she pulled her arm out of her mother's grip.
>
> "I'm in Dumbledore's Army -"
>
> "- a teenagers' gang!" [*I supposed it's been said by George*]
>
> **"A teenagers' gang that's about to take him on, which no one else has dared to do!"** said Fred.
>
> "She's sixteen!" shouted Mrs Weasley. "She's not old enough! What you two were thinking, bringing her with you -"
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

In this scene, Mrs Weasley didn't permit Ginny to fight against Voldemort. I don't understand what Fred was saying: "*A teenagers' gang that's about to take him on, which no one else has dared to do!*". Is 'him' referring to Voldemort? But Voldemort has not been mentioned in the near context.

Comment: What is the purpose of this gang? It is not important for V to be mentioned in the same page or something. If the purpose of the gang is to bring V down, then the pronoun game makes sense. In some religions, He is used to refer to God (Collins). "He/Him" is also used to refer to the big bad.

Comment: @AIQ, I don't know the purpose of this gang because it's the first time I've seen *the gang* in the book.

Comment: Does [this](https://books.google.ca/books?id=DXTFAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=%22A+teenagers%27+gang+that%27s+about+to+take+him+on,+which+no+one+else+has+dared+to+do%22&source=bl&ots=5mHCapVvLK&sig=ACfU3U3UBC1qPv-q4DVO3Fzl2rXWBc6-SA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHz9Xdp8HmAhWrFjQIHQEAB14Q6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22A%20teenagers'%20gang%20that's%20about%20to%20take%20him%20on%2C%20which%20no%20one%20else%20has%20dared%20to%20do%22&f=false) answer your question? It says *"Hogwarts students ... starting and taking leading roles in the last battle against Voldemort."*

Comment: @AIQ, I think I'm okay now.

Comment: It looks like you’ve nearly completed the entire series. Congratulations!

Comment: @Alex Yeah, almost. It's really a hard job for me and I almost gave it up in the middle. I can't make it without the help from people devoted in this site. And you really helped me a lot！Thank you very much! I'll continue to read more English books going forward. :) I feel I've improved a lot after reading those books!

Comment: @dan I frequent this site mostly for your Harry Potter questions, so I'm happy you didn't give up.

Comment: @Alex That's so kind of you!！

Comment: The "- a teenagers' gang!" line is actually said by Mrs Weasley.  She's belittling Dumbledore's Army as a children's group.  Also, "gang" has a negative connotation, since it's is often associated with criminals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, *him* refers to Voldemort. He is never introduced in the discussion probably because he is generally called "You-Know-Who" or "He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named" by the other wizards.